# Android Can not build Project with NDK-Build.cmd from NDK r7

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

When I try to build my android project with JNI, with Android NDK r7. I can not build the project and come to this error. 
Platform- Win Xp SP2
with ndk-build.cmd file that according to developers doc, doesn't need to run from cygwin...

```
usr/bin/sh: del: command not found
make: *** [clean-installed-binaries] Error 127
```

This message indicates that my project is not built properly. Specifically my static library [so file] is not properly linked with apk.

**NB:** I could build with older versions of NDK.....

What is wrong here? According to other posts on internet I have checked that java bin is on windows path.

Comment: I've found a similar problem. I was able to successfully build with NDK r7, but the resulting code didn't run properly. I reverted back to NDK r6b for the time being.

Comment: I am currently building from cygwin- their cmd stuff doesn't work same all the time.... It worked great before I added project into SVN, after it all collapsed..... Cygwin with eclipse is working far better...

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem by removing `C:\cygwin\bin` from `PATH`

Comment: which path and where can i find in eclipse

Answer (score 2):

I just overcomed that problem adding an environment variable ANDROID_NDK_ROOT to the Eclipse project: right button on the project --> Properties --> C++ build --> Environment.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Becuse the prebuilt make execution ported from minGW set the cygwin shell as it's default shell if found. A new one from http://code.google.com/p/mingw-and-ndk/ works.